# Proof of some equality in groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = (G, \cdot_G)$ be a group and assume that $g \in G$ is the only element of $G$ with order $2$, i.e. $g^2 = e$. We want to prove that for all $h \in G$, the equality $h = ghg$ holds.

I tried to calculate the product $(hg) \cdot (gh)^{-1}$, but this way seems to be not really effective (I tried to show that it is equal to the neutral element of $G$, which implies the theorem). Could you give me any tips how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: First show that for all $h$ you have $hgh^{-1} = g$.

Comment: Thanks for hint. It's quite easy to reduce your task to mine, but it's still seems to be hard for me to find the solution. Could you give an another hint?

Comment: Consider what the order of $hgh^{-1}$ can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can verify the property that for any integer $n$,$$(hgh^{-1})^n=hg^nh^{-1}$$
This will help you to prove that the order of $hgh^{-1}$ and $g$ are the same.
By the hypothesis that $g$ is the only element of order $2$, $hgh^{-1}=g$ which implies that $h=ghg^{-1}$.
Since $g$ is of order $2$, $g^2=1$ which implies $g=g^{-1}$.
Hence, $h=ghg.$